# Path in url to access var/www/html files

Tags: files, lamp, url

What should I type in url to see my lamp files.
In localhost is like `"localhost/folder_name/file_name"`
Here, should it be something like `"192.168.0.1/what_here"`?

It goes to my Router page not my lamp files.

Answer (score 0):

The IP address you typed in is most likely your router.  You can check your computer's IP address by going to a terminal screen and typing this command:

```
$ hostname -I
```

The IP you see will be the one you would type in.  To the prefix for a webpage is `http://`.  So you would put that in front of your IP address.

Type this in the address bar:

```
http://192.168.0.x
```

The `x` represent the number you find with the `hostname` command.

You can also alternatively type this in the address field from your computer to see the web site of your local computer:

```
http://localhost
```